# Endless spinning wheel at Woocommerce checkout

Tags: ajax, wordpress, apache, woocommerce

I am in the process of building a shop on wordpress using woocommerce. All is well except that at checkout there is an endless spinning wheel blocking the payment processing.

I have checked the error logs - which show no errors
I have disabled all plug ins - which makes no difference
I have reverted to the default woocommerce shopfront theme - which has the same result.
The console shows no errors.

I have also followed the instructions here https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/endless-loadingspinner-on-the-checkout-page/ which assumes its a memory limit issue. This did not work.

So, after a bit of digging I found some reference here https://mikejolley.com/2015/11/12/debugging-unexpected-token-in-woocommerce-2-4/ and here https://www.maxsangster.com/blog/woocommerce-endless-loading-spinner-on-checkout/

Referring to these two pages I have been able to see that the json response from /?wc-ajax=checkout is just returning HTML which I would imagine is where the issue is.

However I am running an Apache server rather than Nginx as has been mentioned in some threads and articles. Assuming there is a server misconfiguration of the server or something that needs changing what might that be? Bearing in mind that I do not have direct access to this, so will need to be asking someone else to sort it out for me.

And finally if there is something else I can try what might that be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to @plushyObject for generating the spark for this one.

The issue turned out that I had a legacy static html holding page in place as the site's homepage rather than having one set up with wordpress. Simply removing the .html page and letting wordpress's homepage take over solves the problem.

The moral of the story create your holding page in wordpress.

Comment: This worked for me too (upvoted).
Any explanation as to why though?

Comment: You helped me at 1am. I owe you one.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Developer Tools, then Go to the **Network** tab. Click the button and make the request and let that bad boy spin out.

You mentioned the response is returning HTML. Click on the request that goes out that appears to be taking forever (`/?wc-ajax=checkout`) and then click on the **Preview** tab to display that HTML. I bet it shows an error or a clue, anyway.

Comment: I'm afraid not. The preview just shows the HTML for the site's homepage which at present is just a holding page.

Comment: OMG I have just realised the problem! See my answer

Answer (score 0):

In my case the checkout was working fine on Desktop but not on Mobile. After many search on internet I read the solution of @UntitledGraphic.

I had set a redirect in ht-access. The redirect was showing a different home page for mobile. When I removed it, the error gone. I checked back & forth and was sure the ht-access redirect was the problem.

If you have set any redirect in the Htaccess then remove it. This will solve your issue in this case.

I also checked the redirect code on function.php instead of htaccess again the problem appeared. So finally removed the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case the redirection was the issue. So I had to delete the redirect I created via Cpanel.